# Is a geodesic in the 4d spacetime still a geodesic after projection onto the 3d space?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, geodesics

According to Einstein's general relativity, a free object traces a geodesic in the 4d curved spacetime. But what we can observe is the projected path of the object onto the 3d space, which is itself a Riemannian manifold, with the inherited Riemannian metric from the spacetime.

> Is the projected geodesic onto the 3d space still a geodesic?

We know in a flat space, a straight line projected to a subspace remains straight. But I'm not sure whether this is true for a geodesic in a curved space. I guess my question is how the [geodesic equation in the spacetime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesics_in_general_relativity)
$$\frac{d^2x^{\mu}}{ds^2} + \Gamma^{\mu}_{\alpha\beta}\frac{dx^{\alpha}}{ds}\frac{dx^{\beta}}{ds}=0$$
changes when we only look at components $x^1,x^2,x^3$ (with $x^0 $ being the time $t$) in the 3d space.

**Edit 1:**
I forgot to mention my background. I am familiar with Riemannian geometry, but I haven't studied general relativity yet besides some casual reading here and there. But this question was stuck in my head long enough so I guess this is the time I let the demon come out. I will appreciate if you can explain your answer in a level suitable for a beginner in general relativity.

Comment: What is the spatial metric? If $g_{ab}$ depends on time, there is no definite spatial metric. In this case your question is meaningless. If $g_{ab}$ does **not** depend on time, what do you mean for spatial metric? $g_{ab}$ with $a,b=1,2,3?$. It is disputable if $g_{0,a}\neq 0$...

Comment: @ValterMoretti I'm not sure if I understand your concern. But we can always pullback (i.e.,restrict) the Riemannian metric to a submanifold. Essentially, we are saying an inner product on a (tangent) space is still an inner product when restricted to a subspace.

Comment: The term "projection", is somewhat of an "umbrella term". Can you please clarify what you mean by "projection". E.g.: "Stereographic projection", "Cylindrical projection" etc.

Comment: @Matrix001 This is a valid question. What I had in mind was a neighborhood of a point where the spacetime has coordinate $(t,x,y,z)$ with a Riemannian  metric defined there, then the projection is the restriction to the 3d space $(x,y,z)$ with the restricted Riemannian metric. Please let me know if there still is some confusion or any conceptual mistake in general relativity. I forgot to mention that I haven't seriously studied general relativity yet. So I may have made some silly mistake or assumption in my question.

Comment: Thankyou for the clarification! In that case, it is not a "projection", but rather a "3-dimensional slice" of the 4-Dimensional curved space-time, at specific point in time. By finding the first-order partial derivative (in respects to x,y and z) of the function describing the 4-Dimensional curved space-time, you get the function for the "sliced" three-dimensional space. You can compare these functions, and plot them, to see the differences. I hope this extra information is useful!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> But what we can observe is the projected path of the object onto the 3d space, which is itself a Riemannian manifold, with the inherited Riemannian metric from the spacetime.

Not true. To get a 3d space, you have to pick a surface of simultaneity. GR doesn't in general have a preferred surface of simultaneity.

> Is the projected geodesic onto the 3d space still a geodesic?

No. For example, the earth orbits the sun, and the sun's field is approximately static, so that there is a preferred time-slicing. With this time-slicing, space is nearly flat, and the earth's orbit is an ellipse, which is not a geodesic.

Comment: What do you mean by surface of simultaneity? In your example, the surface of simultaneity is the 3d space near the sun?

Comment: @YuhangChen: A surface of simultaneity is a set of points that are all simultaneous. In special relativity, a surface of simultaneity is a 3-dimensional hyperplane that is orthogonal to the observer's four-velocity.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "a set of points (in 3d space?) that are all simultaneous". The term "four-velocity" is also alien to me. Is there any introductory book in GR that explains this and your example in details that I can refer to? Anyway, I accepted this answer. It cleared my doubt (maybe not fully but I guess that's due to my gap in the understanding of GR) in a simplest possible way.

Answer (score 3):

The spatial metric associated to some familly of local observers is the following (in some coordinates system.  I'm using signature $\eta = (1, -1, -1, -1)$):
$$\tag{1}
h_{\mu \nu} = u_{\mu} \, u_{\nu} - g_{\mu \nu},
$$
where $u^{\mu}$ are the components of the 4-velocity of the local observer.  Components (1) define a projector:
$$\tag{2}
h_{\mu \lambda} \, h^{\lambda}_{\; \nu} = h_{\mu \nu}.
$$
Also: $h_{\mu \nu} \, u^{\nu} \equiv 0$ and obviously $h_{\mu}^{\; \lambda} \, g_{\lambda \kappa} \, h^{\kappa}_{\; \nu} \equiv h_{\mu \nu}$.  The 3D spatial section defined with this lower metric depends on the familly of observers you select.

You could then compute the 3D Riemann tensor on that lower space.  The *spacelike* geodesics of that lower space have nothing to do with the *timelike* geodesics of the full 4D metric, despite that (1) is a *projector*.

Notice that the lower metric (1) isn't compatible with the full connection:
$$\tag{3}
\nabla_{\mu} \, h_{\lambda \kappa} = \nabla_{\mu} (u_{\lambda} \, u_{\kappa}) \ne 0.
$$
To define your lower Riemann tensor and also the 3D geodesics, you'll need a new connection $\tilde{\Gamma}_{\mu \nu}^{\lambda}$ from $h_{\mu \nu}$ such that
$$\tag{4}
\tilde{\nabla}_{\mu} \, h_{\lambda \kappa} = 0.
$$